# Какая иерархия категорий будет правильнее с точки зрения оптимизации?

Tags: оптимизация

**Транспорт => Легковые автомобили => Продажа=> BMW**

или

**Транспорт => Продажа =>Легковых автомобилей => BMW**

Соответственно вложенность в url будет такая же, но транслитом.

Также, следует учитывать, что еще есть грузовые авто, спецтехника и другие категории

Comment: Зависит от количества значений в категории. Продажа/Покупка/Кредит - 3 значения, Легковые/Грузовые/Спец/Самолеты/Самокаты... - этих больше. Значит, сначала нужно отсекать то, что больше: вид техники

Comment: прошу прощения, не совсем понял : первый вариант рассматриваем в таком случае ?

Comment: О какой оптимизации речь? Если вопрос про SEO - то для таких вопросов есть отдельная метка.

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса как не соответствующего теме, потому что не относится к программированию.

Answer (score 2):

В целом в данном случае разницы нет. Если посетителю надо быстро выбрать Продажа или Аренда то второй вариант. А если главный выбор это легковые / грузовые то первый. На SEO повлияют скорее названия каталогов и самих страниц